# how to access specific div association with a image

Tags: jquery, css

Trying to change the property of specific div.. can anyone help me in this

```
<div class="photoHolder">
<img src="images/img1.jpg">
<div class="figCap">User description </div>
<h3>User Name</h3>
</div>

<div class="photoHolder">
<img src="images/img2.jpg">
<div class="figCap">User description </div>
<h3>User Name</h3>
</div>
```

Now if i click on any image... i want to change some properties the figCap of that image...

jQuery

```
$(".photoHolder img").click(function(event){ 
$(".figCap").slideToggle();       
});
```

but it changes all the figCap.. i want that only which is associated to that pic only..
help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `this` context with next selector to target desired div:

```
$(".photoHolder img").click(function(event){ 
  $(this).next().slideToggle();       
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `this` as a reference and use `next`.

```
$(".photoHolder img").click(function(event){ 
   $(this).next().slideToggle();       
});
```